# How to find the max number of unique users logged in at once in a day?

Tags: python, pandas

We have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
     users                login               logout  hours
0   User A  2019-08-04 12:30:04  2019-08-04 13:04:42  00:34
1   User A  2019-08-04 09:19:03  2019-08-04 12:30:04  03:11
2   User A  2019-08-04 07:17:51  2019-08-04 08:59:58  01:42
3   User A  2019-08-04 08:59:58  2019-08-04 09:19:03  00:19
4   User A  2019-08-04 13:04:43  2019-08-04 15:30:04  02:25
5   User B  2019-08-04 14:35:17  2019-08-04 14:35:28  00:00
6   User B  2019-08-04 07:03:09  2019-08-04 10:56:23  03:53
7   User B  2019-08-04 10:56:32  2019-08-04 14:35:17  03:38
8   User B  2019-08-04 10:56:23  2019-08-04 10:56:32  00:00
9   User B  2019-08-04 14:35:29  2019-08-04 15:29:09  00:53
10  User C  2019-08-04 09:01:39  2019-08-04 09:19:43  00:18
11  User C  2019-08-04 14:19:56  2019-08-04 15:30:44  01:10
12  User C  2019-08-04 14:02:37  2019-08-04 14:19:56  00:17
13  User C  2019-08-04 11:36:26  2019-08-04 14:02:37  02:26
14  User C  2019-08-04 09:19:43  2019-08-04 11:00:04  01:40
15  User C  2019-08-04 06:56:02  2019-08-04 09:01:39  02:05
```

We would like to find an efficient way to calculate the max number of users that were logged into the system at once throughout the day (~5000 unique users). The data is only for a single day, so there will not be an instance where the data spills over into the next day. Thanks!

Comment: iterate through your rows, and append to some list a calculation that determines the number of logged in users at that moment

Comment: @AlexandreB. how does that answer the question? You're not even checking the login/logout data...

Comment: It is ridiculous how this question can get a +1 when it is not more than a "please do my homework" request. Please at least provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new DataFrame where the timespans are expanded to one row for every second (your smallest resolution). Then it becomes a simple `groupby` + `nunique`, finding the second of the day with the most unique users.

```
import pandas as pd
#df['login'] = pd.to_datetime(df['login'])
#df['logout'] = pd.to_datetime(df['logout'])

res = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(lin, lout, freq='s')).assign(user=usr)
                 for usr, lin, lout in zip(df.users, df.login, df.logout)])

res.groupby(level=0).user.nunique().max()
#3
```

---

It might also be useful to organize the above differently, then you can use `sum(1).max()` to get the most users for any second of the day. `clip` just incase some of the timespans overlap so we still just deal with `nunique`.

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(res.index, res.user).clip(upper=1)

#user                 A  B  C
#row_0                       
#2019-08-04 06:56:02  0  0  1
#2019-08-04 06:56:03  0  0  1
#2019-08-04 06:56:04  0  0  1
#2019-08-04 06:56:05  0  0  1
#2019-08-04 06:56:06  0  0  1
#...                 .. .. ..
#2019-08-04 15:30:40  0  0  1
#2019-08-04 15:30:41  0  0  1
#2019-08-04 15:30:42  0  0  1
#2019-08-04 15:30:43  0  0  1
#2019-08-04 15:30:44  0  0  1
```